# Does JSON require everything be quoted?

Tags: json

`"success":true`, is it same as `"success":"true"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON requires that keys and string values are properly delimited with `"` quotes.  Other values should not have quotes.  This means that `"success":true` and `"success":"true"` are not the same — the first is a boolean value and the second is a string value.

For more information, see http://json.org.

Comment: So other values don't need quotes ^^

Comment: @MatTheCat: rushed it a little bit.  It's fixed now :-)

Comment: Even the attribute name itself doesn't need to have quotes. e.g {name:"tshao"}. But sometimes it causes problems in WCF, Web services client call

Comment: @tshao: Quotes *are* required for names in JSON, but they're not required for a JavaScript object literal.  The two are different things entirely.  Your example would not parse correctly with a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

no. The first is a boolean (true) the second is a string "true"